# Script shell - format row data into a yaml format

Tags: bash, shell, formatting, yaml

I'm looking to find out how using a shell script we could transform something like e.g. :

```
default.aaa.bbb.ccc value1
default.aaa.bbb.ddd value2
default.aaa.xxx.yyy valu3
required.aaa.eee value4
```

into a std yaml format, so something like:

```
default:
  aaa:
    bbb:
      ccc: value1
      ddd: value2
    xxx:
      yyy: valu3
required:
  aaa:
    eee: value4
```

To ease the problem we can assume we take a file as input and that we expect one other file as output.

Comment: Could you have default:   bbb:     ddd: value3 as a valid entry or does it need to be nested alongside the aaa? And as this is very bespoke you're better off giving us a proper data set and showing your attempts so far.

Comment: hi,
Yes default: bbb: ddd: value3 is a valid entry. The main point is that whitespace indentation is used for denoting structure

Comment: @DrCyclotron: Are you allowed to use an external tool like `yq` for this?

Comment: hi,
Yes default: bbb: ddd: value3 is a valid entry. The main point is that whitespace indentation is used for denoting structure.

so this data set
`default.aaa.bbb.ccc value1
default.aaa.bbb.ddd value2
default.bbb.ddd value3
required.aaa.eee value4`

becomes

`default:
  aaa:
    bbb:
   ccc: value1
   ddd: value2
  bbb:
    ddd: value3

required:
  aaa:
    eee: value4`

Comment: @Inian...don't know yq...but if it can solve my issue...I'm not against the idea

Comment: In the end, I expect from this data set to be formated a bit like the 'tree' command in linux do on directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$1
OUTPUT=$2

touch $OUTPUT
while read LINE; do
    echo "$LINE"
    YAML_PATH=$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $1}')
    VALUE=$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $2}')
    yq w -i "$OUTPUT" "$YAML_PATH" "$VALUE"
done < $INPUT
```

`-i` means "update the yaml file inplace".

Caution: your input file should end with a newline.

Comment: ...how to say...it's just amazing !! Thanks a lot @LingSamuel

Comment: only point is that if I add an empty line at the end of the input file, the output file is cleaned. So I don't and it works fine!